# WCF works only with the Web.config is checked for edition

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, tfs, web-config, isoneway

I've a problem. I've created a WCF in .Net 4.0. This is the contract used:

```
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Proccess(byte [] importRequest, int idTask);
```

The service works fine only when the web.config for the WCF is checked for edition ("Check out" mode). When I do a "check in" the web.config file switch and the service does not work.

BUT, if I "check out" the web.config (without any change), the service works again.

When the web.config isn't checked for edition, the application calls to "Proccess" and continue without throw any error but the service is never executed.

Any idea?

Comment: By "check in" and "check out" I assume you mean from your source code control system? What are you using? And when you say "the web.config file switch" how does it change? If you do a binary diff before and after a checkin, is the file different at all?

Comment: I using TFS and "the web.config file switch" means that the status for the file in local environment, when edit the file, it's marked as "check out", and when I execute a check in, the file change to "protected" or "locked" I dont know the exact words